# How do you resize UIView in UIViewContentModeCenter?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, size

I don't get it. I'm using UIView instead of imageView. How can I resize an object form "UIView" in UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeCenter? I've tried this.

```
ObjectUIview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

It doesn't work. But it works on imageview not UIview.  I tried to make window look like gui. I can't make UIview fullscreen and Normal Fit. Can anyone help me out?

```
            //---single tap---

            case 1: {
                //ObjectUIview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            } break;



            //---double tap---

            case 2: {
                //ObjectUIview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
                imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

            } break;
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, check the docs for contentMode and be sure that this does what you think it does: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html